# Simplify set theory expression, need guidience

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm really struggling to understand how to get expression
$$
(x \in A \lor x \in B \lor x \in C) 
\land \lnot 
\bigl( x \in ((B \cap A^{\mathrm{c}}) 
\cup (C \cap A^{\mathrm{c}})) \bigr)
$$
to $x \in A$, $x \in B$, $x \in C$.

I understand that I can change $\cup$ to $\lor$ and $\cap$ to $\land$, but then there is no laws that apply to simplify/rewrite this? I've spent hours and cannot find any material to move forward, would appreciate if some soul could explain. Thank you!

Comment: Before thinking about symbolic manipulations, make sure you understand what the symbols mean. Do you understand what the given expression is saying about $x$ and the sets $A,B,C$? Think about the Venn diagram.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: So picture I uploaded I interpret it like this: (x is an element of A or x is an element of B or x is an element of C) and not(x is an element of (B and not C) or (C and not A)).  I hope I understood you question. My problem lies in how to get "rid"of "or,and" to get to x is an element of A, x is an element of B, x is an element of C. I assume I should be able to rewrite this with support of different laws, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Hint: if you know whether $x$ is in $A$, can you determine whether the statement is true?

Comment: that was tricky, hmm I would say yes. But I don't know if I fully understand

Comment: maybe you could have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29?wprov=sfla1) it says union distributes over intersection (and viceversa), and what this actually means.

Comment: I read that and I understand but I'm struggling with understanding how I could be left with only x∈A, x∈B, x∈C. I drew Venn diagrams and I get correct answer, only A is "coloured". But what I do not understand is how do I get rid of ∨ and ∧.

Comment: $\lnot (A \cup B) = \lnot A \cap \lnot B $ (or, if you prefer $ (A \cup B)^c =  A^c \cap  B^c $) chances are you are going to have to expand all the expression to get to desired result. Welcome to SE by the way

Comment: Proposed manipulation for the RHS: $\lnot (x \in \ldots)$ will be $x \notin (\ldots)$ i.e. $x \in (\ldots)^c$

Comment: Thus, using DeMorgan: $x \in ((B^c \cup A) \cap (C^c \cup A))$ i.e. $x \in (B^c \cup A) \land x \in (C^c \cup A)$

Comment: And this in turn is: $x \in A \lor (x \in B^c \land x \in C^c)$

Comment: Now "add" the LHS and continue that way until $x \in A$.